# Expresión regular para validar sólo letras y espacios acentos. La que me funciona no acepta espacios

Tags: javascript, regex

Esta expresión funciona, pero quiero que acepte espacios.

```js
function cambiarNombre(nombre) {
  let regex = /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+(\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]*)*[a-zA-   ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+$/g;
  return regex.exec(nombre)[0];

}
console.log(cambiarNombre("ñoñerías "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar con esta regla, espero te funcione:

```js
function cambiarNombre(nombre){
 let regex = /^[A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúñÑ ]+$/g;
return regex.test(nombre);

}
console.log(cambiarNombre("ñoñerías "));
```