# devolver mensaje ordenado

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones, else

función Clave(), que tome un parámetro un conjunto de caracteres y devuelva el mensaje de manera ordenada.

Por ejemplo:

Clave( [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"] );
// El resultado es:
"El día es lunes";

Otro ejemplo:

Clave( ["a", "*", "d", "a", "r", "f", "*", "i", "c", "*", "s", "e", "d", " ", "e", "*", "v", "a", "l", "C"] );
// El resultado es:
"Clave descifrada";

Se me ocurrio programarlo asi:

```
function laClaveSecreta(letras){
let uno = ["a", "*", "d", "a", "r", "f", "*", "i", "c", "*", "s", "e", "d", " ", "e", "*", "v" ,"a", "l", "C"];
let dos = [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"];
     if (uno ) {
         return "Clave descifrada";
     }else if (dos ){
         return "El día es lunes"; 
     }
 }
```

pero el valor de "dos" no lo muestra.

La única restricción es que no puedo usar console.log, tengo que usar return.

Comment: Pues pareciera que solo tienes que invertir el arreglo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debido a que no ofreces muchos detalles sobre las restricciones de entrada de la función, y tomando como base los dos ejemplos que colocas, asumiré que la función toma como válido:

- Cualquier letra de la ***A*** a la ***Z*** (incluyendo la ***Ñ***)
- Vocales con acento
- Espacios

Cualquier otro caracter que no cumpla con las restricciones antes mencionadas, será ignorado. Existen muchas formas de solucionar el problema, te explico mi solución, traté de hacerla lo más sencilla y entendible posible.

Primero usamos un `for` para recorrer la cadena carácter por carácter pero de forma inversa. Luego evaluamos si el el carácter en cuestión cumple con las restricciones que nos propusimos. Para ello tomé la [expresión regular de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/199163/199708), eliminando las mayúsculas de la expresión; agregando [la bandera i](https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction#flags) para hacer la expresión *case insensitive*, es decir, insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas; la ñ; y el espacio. Si el carácter cumple con esas restricciones entonces procedemos a "apilarlo" a una cadena que finalmente devolveremos cuando termine el recorrido.

Otra cosa que debes de tener en cuenta es que tu función debería de ser capaz de tratar otras entradas distintas a los ejemplos.

```js
function laClaveSecreta(letras) {
  const regex = /^[a-záéíóúñ ]/i;
  let clave = '';
  for(let i = letras.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(letras[i].match(regex)) {
      clave += letras[i];
    }
  }
  return clave;
}
 
const uno = ["a", "*", "d", "a", "r", "f", "*", "i", "c", "*", "s", "e", "d", " ", "e", "*", "v" ,"a", "l", "C"];

const dos = [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"];

console.log(laClaveSecreta(uno));
console.log(laClaveSecreta(dos));
console.log(laClaveSecreta(['l', 'o', 'b', 'r', 'Á']));
```

Una versión más corta usando [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) y [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
function laClaveSecreta(letras) {
  return letras.filter(l => l.match(/^[a-záéíóúñ ]/i)).reverse().join('');
}
 
const uno = ["a", "*", "d", "a", "r", "f", "*", "i", "c", "*", "s", "e", "d", " ", "e", "*", "v" ,"a", "l", "C"];

const dos = [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"];

console.log(laClaveSecreta(uno));
console.log(laClaveSecreta(dos));
console.log(laClaveSecreta(['l', 'o', 'b', 'r', 'Á']));
```

Comment: pues realmente no hay restricciones, la unica es que cundo lo corro, me pide que no use console.log, la unica pista que me da es: Revisá bien los ejemplos y pensá que está pasado con uno de los caracteres que recibe la función.

Comment: De acuerdo, ya mejoré la explicación, presioné el botón de publicar la respuesta antes de tiempo jeje. Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score -1):

```
function laClaveSecreta(letras) {
  return letras.filter(l => l.match(/^[a-záéíóúñ ]/i)).reverse().join('');
}
 
const uno = ["a", "*", "d", "a", "r", "f", "*", "i", "c", "*", "s", "e", "d", " ", "e", "*", "v" ,"a", "l", "C"];

const dos = [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"];
```

Comment: Bienvenida/o a [es.so]; haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Es importante que expliques brevemente qué hace el código que proporcionas y qué solución proporciona al autor de la pregunta: lee [answer].